# alarm and notification not triggered at specified time

Tags: android, triggers, notifications, alarmmanager

I am trying to trigger a notification and an alarm at a specified time. I have put log information to console to see if the correct time is being set and it is fine. However, still the alarm is not being triggered. Please help.

/***Code for Creating Notification and Alarm***/

```
btn_add_task.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                db.addTask(new DataModel(input_task_title.getText().toString(),input_task_desc.getText().toString(),
                        checkBox.isChecked(),txtDate.getText().toString(),txtTime.getText().toString(),isComplete));

                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                //Set notification for the set date and time
                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                if(mHour>12) {
                    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
                } else {
                    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
                }

                Log.i("Alarm at: ",calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"-"+
                        calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"-"+
                        calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)+" at "+
                        calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+
                        calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

                Intent notifyMessage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NotificationMessage.class);
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, notifyMessage, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pi);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.new_task_added,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(AddTask.this,MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
```

/***Notification Message Class***/

```
package com.apps.katz.doer;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by katz on 4/5/16.
 */
public class NotificationMessage extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        showNotification(context);
    }

    private void showNotification(Context context) {
        Log.i("notification","visible");
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,
                new Intent(context,NotificationMessage.class),0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Doer Notification")
                .setContentText("This is a Doer Notification");
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(1,mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Please help what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) of the `setRepeating` method:

> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms, treated as exact.

Your alarms will be inexact always using `setRepeating`, try using [setExact](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) and reprograming the alarm when it's triggered.

Also, try extending `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` instead of `BroadcastReceiver` in `NotificationMessage` in order to be able to wake the service when your app isn't running.

Comment: Hi Jofre,I tried using both setRepeating and setExactAndAllowWhileIdle but didnt work either way. Any other hints please?

Comment: What do you mean by didn't work? Didn't trigger the alarm at the exact time or didn't work at all?

Comment: Didn't trigger the alarm at all.

Comment: I extended my answer, give it a look

Answer (score 0):

Inside btn_add_task listener, set the alarm as below -

```
Intent notifyMessage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NotificationMessage.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, notifyMessage, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);    
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pi);
```

Now, put a log inside onReceive of NotificationMessage class to be sure that the alarm is fired on time.
Hope, now your program will run.

Comment: Can you please try this -  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179957/broadcastreceiver-cannot-show-notification-when-app-closed-killed/37207265#37207265)